How to connect Ruby on Rails project using Chewy (7.6) to AWS OpenSearch 2.17?
I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project (version 7.1.4.1) that uses Chewy (version 7.6) for indexing. Chewy is configured with the Elasticsearch Ruby client (version 7.17.11) to interact with the search engine.
Locally, I'm using Docker with Elasticsearch images:

ES 8.16 (latest) or ES 7.17

All four indexes in my project work perfectly fine in this environment.
Problem
When I try to connect the project to AWS OpenSearch 2.17, I encounter the following error:

I’ve also tested it with:

AWS OpenSearch 1.3
AWS Elasticsearch 7.10

However, the same error occurs across all AWS versions I’ve tried.
I suspect this is a version compatibility issue between Chewy, the Elasticsearch Ruby client, and AWS OpenSearch/Elasticsearch.
Is this a known compatibility issue with AWS OpenSearch or Elasticsearch versions?
If yes, what are the possible fixes or workarounds?
Do I need to upgrade/downgrade any of the libraries or switch to a specific version of AWS OpenSearch?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Config
Chewy Version: 7.6
Elasticsearch Ruby Client: 7.17.11
AWS OpenSearch Versions Tried: 2.17, 1.3
AWS Elasticsearch Version Tried: 7.10

The erros seems to come not from Chewy, but from elasticsearch client gem.
According to this thread one solution/workaround would be to pin the client's version to <7.14
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/1429
If I understand correctly, the error is due to Elasticsearch Ruby Client: 7.17.11 having a license incompatibile with AWS Elasticsearch 7.10 licence (?)
IDK what's the deal with AWS OpenSearch

Thank you very much Greg. I saw this issue but I went on the wrong side. I confirm using elasticsearch <7.14 works when using AWS ElasticSearch 7.10.
I do not solve the answer yet, I'll keep investigating with AWS OpenSearch differences.
